# Skype4Py Sending & Receiving In Group Chats

Tags: python-2.7, skype4py

Basically, I'm trying to create a skype bot with Skype4Py. My current code work fine in legacy (p2p) group chats and in normal message, but not in the new group chats. Here's my code:

```
import Skype4Py 

prefix = "My Bot: "

def command(Message, Status): 
    if Status == 'SENT' or Status == 'RECEIVED':
        msg = Message.Body.lower()
        if (msg == ",help"):
            send(Message, "Hello!")

def send(Message, String):
    final = prefix+String
    Message.Chat.SendMessage(final)

skype = Skype4Py.Skype();
skype.OnMessageStatus = command 
if skype.Client.IsRunning == False: 
    skype.Client.Start() 
skype.Attach();

while True: 
    input('')
```

Answer (score 3):

If your new group chat is "cloud-based chats", Skype4py do not work well.

For example, create a new group chat, then run code follows:

```py
import Skype4Py

skype = Skype4Py.Skype()
skype.Attach()
for chat in skype.Chats :
    print chat.Name
```

Legacy (p2p) group chats is listed, but new (cloud-based) group chat is not listed.

If you want to make your code work well, you have to create a legacy (p2p) group chats.

Please try this:

[Skype FAQ - What are chat commands and roles?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10042/what-are-chat-commands-and-roles)

> To find out what type of chat you're in, simply **type /get name** into the chat window and press Enter.
> If the group name response starts with "**19:...**", you're in a cloud-based chat;
> if the group name response starts with "**#skypename...**", you're in a P2P-based chat.
>
> -- snip --
>
> All new groups created will be cloud-based groups.
> If you want to create a P2P-based group (to make use of the legacy moderator functionality), **type /createmoderatedchat**.
> This will create a new chat group called Empty Group, to which you can add users and use the full list of P2P-based chat commands described below.